# Loop label in Tkinter Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When you click on the button, it displays a list of Labels that goes down. How to make one Label output and update it when clicked

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win= Tk()

win.geometry("1920x1720")
def display_text():
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    tries = 0
    while tries < 10:
        global entry
        string = entry.get()
        tries += 1
        if int(string) > number:
            b = Label(win, text="Your number more than mine", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            b.pack()
            triess = "Your attempts " + str(tries)
            v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            v.pack()
        if int(string) < number:
            c = Label(win, text="Your number less than mine", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            c.pack()
            triess = "Your attempts " + str(tries)
            v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            v.pack()
        if int(string) == number:
            break
    if int(string) == number:
        tries = str(tries)
        d = Label(win, text="Congratulation, you're win", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        d.pack()
        v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        v.pack()
    if int(string) != number:
        number = str(number)
        d = Label(win, text="Unfortunately, you're loser", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        d.pack()
        v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        v.pack()

entry= Entry(win, width= 40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()
ttk.Button(win, text= "Okay",width= 20, command= display_text).pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

I tried to change the positions of any sections of the code and all in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is so tidy keep going! You have to know that you don't need a while loop because every time you click the button (okay) the "display_text" function restarts, so firstly, you should remove the while loop and then replace the while loop with an if statement that check if the tries are less than 10 and then do your code. I will put the edited code with the comments below.
Please try by yourself with these hints and then check the code... Thank you for reading my explanation.
Here is the code:

```
#importing files
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#The root 
win= Tk()
#The auto dimension of the window
win.geometry("1920x1720")
#defining the tries of the play
tries = 0
#function that displays if the user wins or loses and records attempts
def display_text():
    #taking the random number
    number = random.randint(1, 101)
    #Global the variables of the number of tries 
    global tries
    global triess
    #check if the user have more tries or he finished all tries 
    if tries < 10:
        #Globaling the entry variable that contains the box to be used out of the function
        global entry
        #Taking the value of the user try
        string = entry.get()
        #check if the code is more than the random number
        if int(string) > number:
            #printing on screen
            b = Label(win, text="Your number more than mine", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            #showing the label on the screen
            b.pack()
            #define a variable to be used in showing the user the number of attempts and storage the number of tries in it
            triess = "Your attempts " + str(tries)
            #printing on screen
            v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            #showing on screen
            v.pack()
        #check if the code is less than the random number
        if int(string) < number:
            ## All the codes are explained in the previous if statment
            c = Label(win, text="Your number less than mine", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            c.pack()
            triess = "Your attempts " + str(tries)
            v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            v.pack()
        #check if the code is equal to the random number
        if int(string) == number:
            #The number of tries has been converted into a string in order to print it
            tries = str(tries)
            d = Label(win, text="Congratulation, you're win", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            d.pack()
            v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            v.pack()
        #the if statement checks if the user has won to stop increasing the number of tries 
        if int(string) == number:
            pass
        else:
            tries += 1
    #in case there aren't more tries
    else:
        d = Label(win, text="Unfortunately, you're loser", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        d.pack()
        v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        v.pack()

#The box which the user will write in int his prediction
entry= Entry(win, width= 40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.pack()
#button to enter the prediction
ttk.Button(win, text= "Okay",width= 20, command= display_text).pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the while loop inside `display_text()` if you want to show the guess result when the button is clicked.  Also you need to initialize `tries` and `number` outside the function:

```py
# initialize tries and number
tries = 0
number = random.randint(1, 101)

def display_text():
    # declare tries as global variable
    global tries

    if tries >= 10:
        # game is over
        return

    try:
        guess = int(entry.get())
    except ValueError:
        errmsg = Label(win, text="Invalid number", font=("Courier 22 bold"), fg="red")
        errmsg.pack()
        # remove the error message one second later
        errmsg.after(1000, errmsg.destroy)
        return

    tries += 1
    if guess == number:
        d = Label(win, text="Congratulation, you win!", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        d.pack()
        tries = 10  # game over
    else:
        msg = f"Your number {guess} is {'more' if guess > number else 'less'} than mine"
        b = Label(win, text=msg, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        b.pack()
        triess = "Your attempts " + str(tries)
        v = Label(win, text=triess, font=("Courier 22 bold"))
        v.pack()
        if tries >= 10:
            d = Label(win, text=f"Unfortunately, you lose.\nThe number is {number}", font=("Courier 22 bold"))
            d.pack()
```